# Dimmer switch cable: L1 L1 X --> X L N?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I have an old dimmer switch that has the following wiring: X, L1 and L2

I would like to replace it with an I lightwave dimmer switch ([wiring sheet](http://file:///C:/Users/dickr/Downloads/L21EU%20Instructions%20v6.pdf)), which has X, L and N as connection points. Any suggestions how wiring needs to go?

Am I correct with the following?

1. The live wire (seems to be the X in the old dimmer goes into the L of the lightwave)
2. The L1 old of the old dimmer (switched wire out?) goes into the X of the lightwave
3. What about the L2? Does it seem to be a switching wire maybe? There's only current on it when the light is switched on. Should I just connect it to the X (switched out) as well, because lightwave does the switching electronically.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do yourself a diagram of the wires connecting to the old dimmer and then work out the equivalent positions on the new. If you cannot sort this out then **STOP** and get an electrician to do it properly. If you do it incorrectly then may just be a fuse that blows or you could burn the house down.

Comment: My question is mainly, what do I do with the switching wire. According to the lightwave, this is no longer needed as it's done X electronically via hub. Should I just cover it or connect to X as well?

Comment: Your new 'smart' dimmer requires **N**eutral, while your old 'dumb' one does not. Do you have a neutral wire in the box? Don't just assume that all white wires are neutrals - they're not.